# What is the term for the product of a probability and its complement?

Tags: probability, terminology

The *odds* of an event is the quotient of the probability of the event $A$ and its complement; *i.e.* $p/(1-p)$, if $p = P(A)$.

Is there a name for this term: $p(1-p)$? (Also sometimes appearing as $pq$.)

Comment: I've never seen a term for it. You could call it  "the variance of a Bernoulli' I guess, or something similar referencing logistic regression, but  I like what you called it in the title. I expect it could have several names in particular application areas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(So this doesn't go completely unanswered)

I've never seen a term for it.

You could call it "the variance of a Bernoulli' I guess, or something similar referencing logistic regression, but I like what you called it in the title.

I expect it could have several names in particular application areas, but I really don't think I've seen any.